# How do I temporarily hide the Picture in Picture window?

Tags: macos, picture-in-picture

When watching video using Picture in Picture on a Mac, how can the video be temporarily hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the video off the screen to hide it. The video will mostly move off screen with a portion still visible, but blurred. Audio from the video will continue playing.

You can drag or click it to replace the videos position on screen.

Video
https://thumbs.gfycat.com/TatteredOccasionalIaerismetalmark-mobile.mp4